# Can box2d b2BodyDef have a massdata property in Cocos2D?

Tags: flash, cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

I want to know if box2d b2BodyDef has a massdata property or if it can be accessed in some way. I am not sure whether this can be done in Cocos2D but I have seen it in the flash code I am trying to re-implement in cocos2d.
Here is the the code that brought about the question.

```
for ( var i:Number = 0; i < numSections - 1; i++ )
            {
            // One rope section body
            ropeBodyDef.position.Set( 0, starBody.GetPosition().y - dY * i / numSections );
            ropeBodyDef.massData.mass = 0.8 + 0.8 * i / numSections;
                //ropeBody.
            ropeBody = world.CreateBody( ropeBodyDef );            
            ropeBody.CreateShape( ropeShapeDef );

            ropeSegments.push( ropeBody );

            // One rope section joint
            jointDef.Initialize( ropeStart, ropeBody, ropeStart.GetPosition(), ropeBody.GetPosition() );
            joint = world.CreateJoint( jointDef ) as b2DistanceJoint;
            joint.m_length = dY / numSections; // this is probably something bad, but I need it for the whole thing to work.

            // update startpoint for next joint
            ropeStart = ropeBody;
        }
```

can anybody please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

The mass data can be accessed once you create the body:

```
b2Body *body = world->createBody(&bodyDef);
b2MassData massData;
body->GetMassData(&massData);
massData.mass = NEW_MASS;
body->setMassData(&massData);
```

But you could also just set the density through the fixture def:

```
b2FixtureDef fixtureDef;
fixtureDef.density = 1.0;
aBody->createFixture(&fixtureDef);
```